# How to replace certain characters to CR+LF between two words

Tags: sed

I want to generate a csv file to tell what server(s) have particular files and ownership. Here's the original output I got:

```
server01,server02,server03,owner,/etc/file1
server04,owner,/etc/file2
server05,server06,owner,/etc/file3
```

I want to replace the commas between server names with Windows format new line(CF+LR), and add quotes between them so that the CSV will display all the servers in the same box.

Desired output:

```
"server01
server02
server03",owner,/etc/file1
"server04",owner,/etc/file2
"server05
server06",owner,/etc/file3
```

How to achieve it with sed?

Comment: Are all line ending to be `\r\n` or just some of them?

Comment: Apologize it was a typo. It's CSV.  I have corrected that. All lines are ending in Unix format

Comment: “All lines are ending in Unix format”. So where does the `\r\n` come in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with `sed`, I'd use `perl` instead (or maybe `awk` - but then I'd have to write my own `pop()` and `join()` functions instead of using the perl built-ins):

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$file = pop @F; $owner = pop @F;
                  print join(",", "\"" . join("\r\n", @F) . "\"", $owner, $file)' input.csv 
"server01
server02
server03",owner,/etc/file1
"server04",owner,/etc/file2
"server05
server06",owner,/etc/file3
```

First it removes the last two elements (the owner and the filename) from the `@F` array (`@F` is automatically created for each input line because of the `-a` option using commas as the field separator as specified by the `-F,` option - similar to how awk autosplits its input) and stores them in variables `$file` and `$owner`.

`"\"" . join("\r\n", @F) . "\""` constructs a string where each element of @F is separated by CR+LF characters, and the entire string is wrapped in double-quotes.

This string is joined (by commas) with `$owner` and `$file`, and printed.

Comment: NOTE: if the input file has windows CR+LF format, the output will have CR+LF line-endings.  If the input has unix-style LF only line-endings, then the output will have LF-only line-endings.  At least, that's how it works on linux.  The exact details of how perl handles line-endings varies between operating systems.  You can always manually handle the line-endings (and splitting of the input line) yourself, and hard-code whatever line-ending you want.

Comment: You can get the join and some of the pop for free in awk: `awk -F, '{ t=FS $(NF-1) FS $NF; OFS="\r\n"; NF-=2; print "\"" $0 "\"" t}' file` . I'd also use `-vq=\"` to replace the toothpicks, but that spacing may depend on gawk.

Answer (score 4):

If it's everything left of a literal `,owner,` you want to wrap in one field:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E ':1; s/,(.*,owner,)/\r\n\1/; t1; s/(.*)(,owner,)/"\1"\2/' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{.*?(?=,owner,)}{q(") . ($& =~ s/,/\r\n/gr) . q(")}e' file
```

If it's everything except that last two fields:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E ':1; s/(.*),(.*,.*,)/\1\r\n\2/; t1; s/(.*),/"\1",/' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{(.*)(?=,.*,)}{q(") . ($& =~ s/,/\r\n/gr) . q(")}e' file
```

Or using the `Text::CSV` perl module to do CSV parsing and formatting properly:

```
perl -MText::CSV -e '
  $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, decode_utf8 => 0, eol => $" = "\r\n"});
  while ($row = $csv->getline(STDIN)) {
    if (($last = $#{$row}) > 1) {
      $csv->print(STDOUT, ["@$row[0..$last-2]", @$row[$last-1..$last]]);
    } else {
      $csv->print(STDOUT, $row);
    }
  }' < file
```

If the file is encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-8 with BOM, which is not unheard of for Microsoft files, you'll likely have to adapt (see `perldoc Text::CSV` for that approach), or you may prefer to do the reformatting in a `<file dos2unix | ... | unix2dos` way so you can process sane input.

Answer (score 2):

You want to combine the 1st comma-delimited field with all the following fields, up to (but not including) the last two in each record, by quoting them, producing a single quoted CSV field. You then want to replace the embedded commas in that combined field with CR+LF.

You can do this easily enough by reversing the contents of each line in your file, inserting a double quote after the second comma, reversing the line again and inserting a double quote at the start:

```bash
$ rev file | sed 's/,/,"/2' | rev | sed 's/^/"/'
"server01,server02,server03",owner,/etc/file1
"server04",owner,/etc/file2
"server05,server06",owner,/etc/file3
```

Since we now have a properly quoted header-less CSV file, we can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`; a tool *specifically* for working with structured data such as CSV) to replace all commas in the 1st field with CR+LF:

```bash
$ rev file | sed 's/,/,"/2' | rev | sed 's/^/"/' | mlr --csv -N put '$1 = gsub($1, ",", "\r\f")'
server01
server02
server03,owner,/etc/file1
server04,owner,/etc/file2
server05
server06,owner,/etc/file3
```

Note that there is no need to quote the fields as, on a Unix system, field and record separators are not embedded in fields in this data set. We can show this by extracting the second field from each record with a separate call to `mlr`:

```bash
$ rev file | sed 's/,/,"/2' | rev | sed 's/^/"/' | mlr --csv -N put '$1 = gsub($1, ",", "\r\f")' | mlr --csv -N cut -f 2
owner
owner
owner
```

Would you want to retain the original quoting from the output of the last `sed` command, then use `--quote-original`:

```bash
$ rev file | sed 's/,/,"/2' | rev | sed 's/^/"/' | mlr --csv -N --quote-original put '$1 = gsub($1, ",", "\r\f")'
"server01
server02
server03",owner,/etc/file1
"server04",owner,/etc/file2
"server05
server06",owner,/etc/file3
```

Ideally, though, you'd correct whatever code produced this broken CSV output so that the field is correct from the start, instead of fixing it in a post-processing step.

---

Using only Miller:

```bash
mlr --nidx --fs comma put '
    for (var i=2; NF > 3; i=i+1) {
        $1 .= "\r\f" . $[i];
        unset $[i]
    }
    $1 = "\"" . $1 . "\""' file
```

This would read the file as a simple comma-delimited, implicitly indexed, text file.  It would then append the 2nd and later fields onto the end of the 1st field with CR+LF as the delimiter, deleting each appended field until only three fields are left. It then explicitly quotes the 1st field.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for that correction. I have both the 5.10.2 and the 6.4.0 releases installed, but the latter is a bit trickier for me to run (separate local install), so I tend to use the older one. Maybe I should just uninstall the old release.

Comment: Yeah it does seem to be developing fast - I find it hard to keep up! I'd had a play with this myself and come up with something similar using the DSL built in map functions in place of the k,v loop: `put '$* = {1: "\"" . joinv(mapexcept($*,NF-1,NF),"\r\f") . "\"", 2: $[NF-1], 3: $[NF]}'`